# Getting different Value of request.original_fullpath in same html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have added `<%= request.original_fullpath%>` to a partial view.
The partial view is rendered in multiple divs in other views.
It is displaying two different values for `original_fullpath` in a single page.
working fine on local machine, bug on staging/production.

Comment: Can you please post examples of what's outputted on the page?

Comment: on one div the output is /collection/bedsheet and next div its /performance-bedsheet/product-name..
two different urls on same page